# How to retrieve the value of an ID column inside a transaction that is never committed?

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, integration-testing, transactionscope

I am writing some integration tests that test the data access layer for a .NET website that talks to a MS SQL Server database.

I'm using TransactionScope to roll back any changes made during the test like this:

```
public class DatabaseFixture
{
    private TransactionScope _transactionScope;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        _transactionScope.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I want to know the ID of rows that I add in my INSERT statements so my query looks like this `insert into Exercises (Name) Values (@Name); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();`.

Once I added the TransactionScope, SCOPE_IDENTITY() doesn't return the right value any more. It's always returning 1, even though the row might be id 3 or 4. I'm guessing this is to do with the fact that the transactions aren't committed.

Is SCOPE_IDENTITY() not the right way to do this?

Comment: can you try @@IDENTITY?

Comment: Can you show the code actually executing the SQL?

Comment: This question can totally be closed! Hopefully nobody else will repeat my stupid mistake. :)

Answer (score 1):

This had nothing to do with transactions, I was just using the Dapper ORM incorrectly.

I was just using Execute rather than ExecuteScalar to do my insert so it wasn't returning the value of my select.

Here's the code that works:

```
var exerciseQuery = "insert into Exercises (Name) Values (@Name);" +
                    "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
exercise.Id = connection.ExecuteScalar<int>(exerciseQuery, new { Name = name});
```